# C++: Can a class be used as an object in another class?

Tags: c++, class, object

I created two classes,

```
template <typename Object>
class Apple
{
    // some definitions
}

class Ball
{
    Apple green,red;
    //some more definitions
}
```

I get an error saying,

`invalid use of template-name ‘Apple’ without an argument list`

Is it not possible to use a class as an object in another class?

I just started C++ a few days ago. So please go easy.

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible, but your problem has nothing to do with your question. Your example can be simplified to use `Apple` the same way in `main` and the compiler will still complain.

Comment: What did you mean the `Object` template parameter should be? You would declare members of a templated class using a typename for instantiation, e.g.: `Apple<int> red;`

Comment: You have to infer a type for your templated class when you instantiate it, like `Apple<T> green,red;` where `T` is the `typename` used to build your `class` according to your `template`.

Comment: If you want an object of the class declaration itself (like ruby has), no. If you want an instance of the type described by the class, yes.

Comment: @DieterLücking I'm no Ruby guy, how are this things called in Ruby ?

Comment: @Chandan _"So please go easy."_ Usually not, we're serious here.

Comment: @Chandan: I don't think you are using the right tutorials or books if you accidentally define a class template without having learned what that means...

Comment: @user2485710 Even a type (which is not an instance representing the type) is an object in ruby. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can compose an object with another, that is that we call [Object Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

The problem here is you have declared `Apple` as a template class, so it is expecting a type for instantiation.

For instance:

```
class Ball
{
    Apple<int> green,red;   // Note the <int>
    //some more definitions
}
```

When you declare a template class you aren't declared a new type but (forgive the redundancy) a template for a type. Hence, an object is the result of instantiating a class and a class is the result of instantiating a template class.

Comment: @Josh I don't get your comment? And if so? Might not completely solve the OP's misconception, but that's hard to tell :-P ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a class can be used as an object in another class. However, you need to make sure that your declaration is correct. Since `Apple` is a template class, you need to declare it as such when you declare it in `Ball`.

This code:

```
Apple green, red;
```

is as if `Apple` was not a template. However, since `Apple` is a template, you'll need to declare it with the type as follows:

```
Apple<type> green, red;
```

`type` can be any data type that you want to use in `Apple`, such as char, int, double, etc.